# Struggling with Navigation Page in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Before I posted a question here, I did find a solution in Google but it's nothing. Also, I am a beginner.

I try to take my **main Page** (Content Page) to **another page** (Tabbed Page) in Xamarin.Forms, unfortunately, it always gives me

```
I/Choreographer(21345): Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
Java.Lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.ImageView
```

And here is my simple code:

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MelaNet"
         x:Class="ProjectX.MainPage"
<ScrollView>
    <StackLayout Spacing="10" Padding="10">

        <Button x:Name="button" Text="Analyse"/>

    </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
</ContentPage>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs** (Content Page)

```
button.Clicked += async (sender, args) =>
        {
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new TabbedPage1());
        };
```

Both **TabbedPage1.xaml** and **TabbedPage1.xaml.cs** have only a template code.

However, I can take my **MainPage.xaml** to **ContentPage2.xaml** without any error.

I don't quiet understand please give me a guidance.

Cheers

Comment: post your content page code please

Comment: I added my content page in `.xaml`. If you mean in **MainPage.xaml.cs** that is my entire code, just `Clicked` event.

Comment: see the exception says the application might be doing to much work on the main thread which simply means you have alot of stuff in your code behind so show me your partial class (xaml.cs) and the whole xaml file